calculating net exposure to an index
I would like to invest in a portfolio of two inversely correlated ETFs, with funds allocated at a ratio. The two funds track the performance of the same underlying index: the share price of NVDA (called NVDAX). The first fund, NVDD, tracks the underlying index NVDAX at a multiple of -1X the index's daily return. The other fund, NVDL, tracks NVDAX at a multiple of 1.5X the index's daily return.
Given this, can you tell me the ratio of funds I should allocated to each ETF in order to achieve the following net exposure levels to the underlying index: -25%, -20%, -15%, -10%, 0%, 10%, 15%?
By way of example, assuming a portfolio consists of USD 60,000 worth of NVDD and USD 40,000 worth of NVDL, and NVDAX goes down by 1% on a given day. The portfolio would not change in value, as the net exposure to NVDAX is 0%: the 60,000 of NVDD would increase in value by 1% or 600, while the 40,000 of NVDL would decrease by 1.5%, also 600.
My goal now is to understand the ratio of allocations necessary the achieve other exposure levels. Thus, if NVDAX goes down by 1%, with a 25% exposure level to NVDAX, for example, the portfolio would go down by .25%.
I hope I formed this question correctly. Thank you for any help.

So the return on one fund is: $1.5\alpha$ 
And the return on the other is: $-1.0\alpha$ 
Where $\alpha$ is the return of your index.
And you want to target a specific return as a multiple of your index, say $\lambda \alpha$ where all your capital is allocated, i.e. $x_1 + x_2 = 1.0$, if the x's are fractions of your capital.
Then you have a system of two equations:
$$
1.5x_1 -1.0x_2 = \lambda \\
x_1 + x_2 = 1.0
$$
Which implies
$$x_1 = \frac{\lambda + 1}{2.5}\\ x_2 = \frac{1.5 - \lambda}{2.5} $$
In your example you target a net exposure of zero. I.e. $\lambda=0.0$, and you obtain the weights: 40% and 60%.
